# Integrate log(x) Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

How can `1/ln(x)` be integrated in *Matlab*?

```
y=0:.1:1;
a=log(y);
plot(a,y);
z=quad(a,-2,2);
```

I thought this would work.

Comment: I don't see any integration there, and it looks like you've passed the independent and dependent variable to `plot` in the wrong order.

Comment: http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/definite-integrals.html I tried it with q = quad(FUN, A, B)

Comment: But `a` is a variable, not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
z = quad(@(x) 1./log(x), 2, 10)
```

and gives the result

```
z = 5.1204
```

You can't integrate across the interval -2:2, because the natural logarithm is undefined at x = 0, and at x = 1, the natural logarithm is 0, so the reciprocal isn't defined.